# How to restrict the character when the length is out of 20 characters in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to generate a text file and inside generate the employee name and the length should 20. eg, if the name length is above 20 display only first 20 characters, if the name length is below 20, first display the name and leading character fill with blank space (left aligned).

I tried the following example
**1)**

```
select right('                    ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, 'Merbin Joe'), 20);
```

But this will add the fill with blank space before the name, but I need to fill after the name

**2)**

```
select left('                    ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, 'Merbin Joe'), 20)
```

But this is fill the 20 blank space first.

Comment: `select left(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), 'Merbin Joe') + '                    ' , 20)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one with `left` is almost correct, except that you have to add spaces after the string, not before:

```
select
    left(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, 'Merbin Joe') + replicate(' ', 20), 20)
```

Comment: I need to display like 'Merbin Joe          ', but It doesn't show the last space.

Comment: @MerbinJoe, the query returns me `Merbin Joe          `, i.e. the string is padded with spaces in the end if it is shorter than 20 symbols. (Unfortunately extra spaces are trimmed in comments).

Comment: If the name is 'Merbin Joe' 10 blank space at the end.

Comment: @MerbinJoe, yes, isn't you asked about that in _if the name length is below 20, first display the name and leading character fill with blank space (left aligned)._ ?

Comment: @MerbinJoe, how do you check the result? In SSMS if I copy output and inspect it, I see that name is padded with spaces. You may do additional check by enclosing the resuilt string into square brackets with `select quotename(left(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, 'Merbin Joe') + replicate(' ', 20), 20))`. This returns `[Merbin Joe          ]` (10 spaces before the closing bracket).

Comment: woundn't it simpler to just CONVERT(NCHAR(20), ''Merbin Joe') ?

Comment: @MerbinJoe, see the answer posted by Squirrell with `convert(nchar(20)...` method, and consider moving accept mark.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, 'Merbin Joe') + SPACE(20), 20)
```

Answer (score 2):

it sounds like you want to RIGHT align the text ?

```
SELECT RIGHT ( REPLICATE(' ', 20) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), 'Merbin Joe'), 20)
```

if you want to LEFT align the text and pad spaces behind

```
SELECT CONVERT(NCHAR(20), 'Merbin Joe')
```